# How to create separate DDL file for create tables and constraints in DB2

Tags: db2, ddl, db2-luw

For DB2 10.1 LUW, I want to create a DDL script which just contains the create table statements and then create a DDL script which just contains the constraints.

The aim is to automate the creation of the database scripts from the existing database and not rely on SQL GUIs to do this like Data Studio, SQLDbx and RazorSQL.  Ideally we would like to trigger actions from the command line that can generate the create DLL for the schema, the insert data statements for each table in the schema and then generate the constraints DDL.  This will help us to insert the data without dealing with the constraints which will help performance and means we will not be restricted to running the inserts in a specific order.

Unfortunately we cannot use db2move and I thought db2look would work for the DDL, but cannot find the syntax to do this.  Can db2look do this or is there anything else out there that could help?

Thanks

Comment: `db2look` writes all DDL statements in one file, so you'll have to either manually split that file or script the operation.

Comment: Thanks Mustaccio.   I will look into scripting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

db2look generates DDL script from existing DB and objects.

For example,
 1. Getting all DDL for a DB

```
db2look -d <dbname> -a -e -l -x -o db2look.out
```

2. To get DDL for a table

   db2look –d dbname –e –z schema_name –t Table_name -o output_file -nofed